# css property for changing font color of links

Tags: css, custom-masterpage

Which CSS property changes color of fonts of links in SharePoint 2013. I want to do the changes in customized master page of `mysite15.master`.

Comment: Take a look at creating a custom .spcolor file since you're using 2013. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all links:

```
a:link
{
   color: #000000;
}
```

For all links where class="whatever":

```
a.whatever:link
{
   color: #000000;
}
```